# Adobe Reader Printing Concern

Tags: adobe

I am using command line version of Adobe Reader DC to print PDF file.

I am getting PDF file having some pages with more width and having content like it fit to landscape page.

selecting printer to print this file with Letter size. 2550 * 3300.

So in output all TIF should be generated with Letter size.

My concern is with generated output TIF files,

**Default Setting** :

**Orientation** : Auto Potrait/Landscape Orienation and **PageSize** : Shrink Oversized Pages

1. With default printing setting, pages with higher width are rotated (Image dimensions : 2550 * 3300)
2. With selection of check box (Choose paper source by pdf size) , rotation issue resolved but Image dimension not consistent to Letter size.

Is there any way we can print images with  Auto Potrait/Landscape Orienation and can maintain Image dimension with letter size ?

Like if Page with higher width can be printed with Landscape orienation at that time Image dimensions : 3300* 2550 ?

I want each page to print properly as per selection of size(ex: Letter,A4 etc..)

**Note**: if i do not select 'Choose paper source by pdf size' then pages with higher width gets rotated.

Comment: There is not a command line version of Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: I mean Adobe Reader command line version to print file.